# Issue with Docker Compose Up when installing composer syntax error: unexpected end of file (expecting "then")

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to do command : docker-compose up, but in some weird reason when it gets to the point running install-composer.sh script it gives error ::

```
 not foundomposer.sh: line 4: 
./install-composer.sh: line 17: syntax error: unexpected end of file (expecting "then")
ERROR: Service 'php' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apk add --update --no-cache git $COMPOSER_DEPS         && chmod u+x install-composer.sh         && ./install-composer.sh         && composer --version         && apk del --purge $COMPOSE
R_DEPS' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

This is the script im trying to run:

```
EXPECTED_SIGNATURE="$(wget -q -O - https://composer.github.io/installer.sig)"
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
ACTUAL_SIGNATURE="$(php -r "echo hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php');")"

if [ "$EXPECTED_SIGNATURE" != "$ACTUAL_SIGNATURE" ]
then
    >&2 echo 'ERROR: Invalid installer signature'
    rm composer-setup.php
    exit 1
fi

php composer-setup.php --quiet
RESULT=$?
rm composer-setup.php
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
exit $RESULT
```

Thanks on your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like formmating aws bad, ive used Notepad++ and formated text to Unix(LF).

Worked like a charm, hope it saves someones time.